# Trouble connecting cloud9 environment to DocumentDB cluster (hangs)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb, aws-cloud9

I have a document DB cluster and am trying to connect to it using a cloud9 environment. I am doing this with this command `mongo --host docdb-2023-06-08-15-56-01.cluster-cuz2po50vpwx.us-east1.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017 --username LambdaPOC1 --password <insertYourPassword>` (filling in the correct password). The command just hangs in the cloud9 terminal

What I have checked:

1. The cloud9 environment and DocumentDB cluster are in the same VPC.
2. The security group for the cluster has an inbound rule that has the correct source (the cloud9 security group) and the correct port (27017)
3. TLS is disabled

I am relatively new to AWS so I don't want to post any images of security configurations that should not be public, but let me know what you need that's safe to post.

Comment: It sounds like you have it configured correctly. First thing to check is whether the cluster URL is resolving to a **private IP address** (which is required for referencing other Security Groups, and good for speed+costs too). Then, you can _temporarily_ change the Inbound rule on the cluster to allow traffic from `0.0.0.0/0` on port 27017 and see if that fixes it (which indicates the IP range is having a problem). If that doesn't work, try opening it to all ports too. Also, make sure nobody has modified the NACLs, which should be on the default "Allow All" configuration.

Comment: I tried everything mentioned by @JohnRotenstein but it didn'tt work. I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67377863/4214037. In my case, I disabled TLS before too and restarting documentDB cluster worked.